# Password for a command run over SSH appearing in clear text

Tags: unix, ssh, remote-access

I have a laptop through which I connect to a server through SSH.
On the server, I typically have to run a command that authenticates me and fetches some credentials for the current session (let's call the command foo-creds)

Typically, if I perform an SSH first

```
$ ssh my-remote-server
```

and then in my SSH session run:

```
$ foo-creds
```

It prompts me for a password, and when I enter my password it appears blank (due to *nix based systems hiding the password for security reasons).

However, when I run the command as a part of SSH directly from my mac:

```
$ ssh my-remote-server foo-creds
```

It prompts me for a password but the password appears as plain-text (i.e. visible on the terminal).

**Question: How do I make it work so that it appears as hidden even when executed as a part of the SSH command on my laptop?**

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1138707/ssh-makes-all-typed-passwords-visible-when-command-is-provided-as-an-argument-to/1138716

Comment: Yes, I would also try Martheen's suggestion: `ssh -t remote-server foo-creds`  but it may depend on how exactly foo-creds works.

Comment: Thanks @Martheen and @Ralf Ulrich. `-t` works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer already exists at [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1138707/ssh-makes-all-typed-passwords-visible-when-command-is-provided-as-an-argument-to/1138716).

```
$ ssh -t remote_server foo-creds
```

Simple explanation is that this forces allocation of a TTY to the ssh session which supports password hiding.

---

*Thanks to @Martheen for providing the link!*